# Code Igniter: Most used methods in one area

Tags: php, codeigniter, dry

In my CI controllers I have these three functions:

```
function _temp ($view,$data="") {
  $this->load->view('temp/nm-header',$data);
  $this->load->view($view,$data);
  $this->load->view('temp/footer',$data);
}

function _qs($val) {
  return $this->session->userdata($val);
}

function _qp($val) {
  return $this->input->post($val);
}
```

I would like to have a central controller for this, rather than to have to copy/paste these methods in every controller I have. Will making a library do the trick? If so...

```
$ci =& get_instance
```

How do I make this variable above be available in all of the menthods I have in my library class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create a library. Instead, create a base controller called `MY_Controller` for your common methods, and have your other controllers extend from it, like this:

MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function _temp ($view,$data="") {
        $this->load->view('temp/nm-header',$data);
        $this->load->view($view,$data);
        $this->load->view('temp/footer',$data);
    }

    function _qs($val) {
        return $this->session->userdata($val);
    }

    function _qp($val) {
        return $this->input->post($val);
    }

}
```

Any other controller you want to have access to your common methods:

```
class Some_controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // _temp(), _qs(), and _qp() are now all available to any controller
    // that extends MY_Controller

}
```

Comment: Can I put My_controller in the controller folder? or should I put it in the core?

Comment: @MrA: You should put it in the `core` directory. See the ["Extending Core Classes" section of the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own core-classes and extend the CI-ones.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: In my core-class, for the one that I am asking, do I have to extent my class to the CI_controller?

Comment: Controller -> MY_Controller -> CI_Controller